# Why wont LitJSON work in build, but does work in the editor?

Tags: json, user-interface, unity-game-engine, build, litjson

I am working in Unity, and I am trying to use LitJSON for an inventory and ability system, as well as stats. I made that work, and it all works via some functions I put in a script. In unity, it works really well. However, when I build the game for pc standalone, all of the data from the JSON files doesn't work, and the UI shows blank text.

Here is my Character Stat Control functions script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;
using LitJson;
using System.Linq;


public class Character
{
    public string Name      { get; set; }
    public int Id           { get; set; }
    public int Strength     { get; set; }
    public int Intelligence { get; set; }
    public int Defense      { get; set; }
    public int Resistance   { get; set; }
    public int Accuracy     { get; set; }
    public int Agility      { get; set; }
    public int Speed        { get; set; }
    public int MaxAP        { get; set; }
    public int CurrentAP    { get; set; }
    public int MaxHP        { get; set; }
    public int CurrentHP    { get; set; }
    public int Affinity     { get; set; }

    public Character() {

    }
}

public class CharacterStats : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static string character1FilePath = "/Resources/character1Stats.json";
    public static string character2FilePath = "/Resources/character2Stats.json";
    public static string character3FilePath = "/Resources/character3Stats.json";
    public static string character4FilePath = "/Resources/character4Stats.json";


    public static string GetName (int characterID) {
        Character character = new Character ();
        string characterString;
        switch (characterID) {
        case 1:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText (Application.dataPath + character1FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.Name;

        case 2:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + character2FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.Name;

        case 3:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + character3FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.Name;

        case 4:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + character4FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.Name;

        default:
            return null;

        }
    }

    public static int GetStrength (int characterID) {
        Character character = new Character ();
        string characterString;
        switch (characterID) {
        case 1:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText (Application.dataPath + character1FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.Strength;

        case 2:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + character2FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.Strength;

        case 3:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + character3FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.Strength;

        case 4:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + character4FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.Strength;

        default:
            return 0;

        }
    }

    public static int GetIntelligence (int characterID) {
        Character character = new Character ();
        string characterString;
        switch (characterID) {
        case 1:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText (Application.dataPath + character1FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.Intelligence;

        case 2:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + character2FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.Intelligence;

        case 3:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + character3FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.Intelligence;

        case 4:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + character4FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.Intelligence;

        default:
            return 0;

        }
    }


    public static int GetDefense (int characterID) {
        Character character = new Character ();
        string characterString;
        switch (characterID) {
        case 1:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText (Application.dataPath + character1FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.Defense;

        case 2:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + character2FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.Defense;

        case 3:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + character3FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.Defense;

        case 4:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + character4FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.Defense;

        default:
            return 0;

        }
    }


    public static int GetResistance (int characterID) {
        Character character = new Character ();
        string characterString;
        switch (characterID) {
        case 1:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText (Application.dataPath + character1FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.Resistance;

        case 2:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + character2FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.Resistance;

        case 3:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + character3FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.Resistance;

        case 4:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + character4FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.Resistance;

        default:
            return 0;

        }
    }


    public static int GetAccuracy (int characterID) {
        Character character = new Character ();
        string characterString;
        switch (characterID) {
        case 1:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText (Application.dataPath + character1FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.Accuracy;

        case 2:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + character2FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.Accuracy;

        case 3:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + character3FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.Accuracy;

        case 4:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + character4FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.Accuracy;

        default:
            return 0;

        }
    }

    public static int GetAgility (int characterID) {
        Character character = new Character ();
        string characterString;
        switch (characterID) {
        case 1:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText (Application.dataPath + character1FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.Agility;

        case 2:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + character2FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.Agility;

        case 3:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + character3FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.Agility;

        case 4:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + character4FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.Agility;

        default:
            return 0;

        }
    }

    public static int GetSpeed (int characterID) {
        Character character = new Character ();
        string characterString;
        switch (characterID) {
        case 1:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText (Application.dataPath + character1FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.Speed;

        case 2:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + character2FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.Speed;

        case 3:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + character3FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.Speed;

        case 4:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + character4FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.Speed;

        default:
            return 0;

        }
    }

    public static int GetMaxAP (int characterID) {
        Character character = new Character ();
        string characterString;
        switch (characterID) {
        case 1:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText (Application.dataPath + character1FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.MaxAP;

        case 2:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + character2FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.MaxAP;

        case 3:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + character3FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.MaxAP;

        case 4:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + character4FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.MaxAP;

        default:
            return 0;

        }
    }

    public static int GetCurrentAP (int characterID) {
        Character character = new Character ();
        string characterString;
        switch (characterID) {
        case 1:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText (Application.dataPath + character1FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.CurrentAP;

        case 2:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + character2FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.CurrentAP;

        case 3:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + character3FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.CurrentAP;

        case 4:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + character4FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.CurrentAP;

        default:
            return 0;

        }
    }

    public static int GetMaxHP (int characterID) {
        Character character = new Character ();
        string characterString;
        switch (characterID) {
        case 1:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText (Application.dataPath + character1FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.MaxHP;

        case 2:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + character2FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.MaxHP;

        case 3:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + character3FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.MaxHP;

        case 4:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + character4FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.MaxHP;

        default:
            return 0;

        }
    }

    public static int GetCurrentHP (int characterID) {
        Character character = new Character ();
        string characterString;
        switch (characterID) {
        case 1:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText (Application.dataPath + character1FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.CurrentHP;

        case 2:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + character2FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.CurrentHP;

        case 3:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + character3FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.CurrentHP;

        case 4:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + character4FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.CurrentHP;

        default:
            return 0;

        }
    }

    public static int GetAffinity (int characterID) {
        Character character = new Character ();
        string characterString;
        switch (characterID) {
        case 1:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText (Application.dataPath + character1FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.Affinity;

        case 2:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + character2FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.Affinity;

        case 3:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + character3FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.Affinity;

        case 4:
            characterString = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + character4FilePath);
            character = JsonMapper.ToObject<Character> (characterString);
            return character.Affinity;

        default:
            return 0;

        }
    }
}
```

This script is used all over the game, and the values of the stats are displayed on the screen:
[image]

However, this is what it looks like when I actually build it:[image]

Comment: Where did you place the json files?

Comment: in /Resources in the assets folder

Comment: That's what I thought was the problem. This problem has nothing to do with LitJSON . Check the duplicated question for how to read Text files placed in the Resources folder. `File.ReadAllText` should not be used for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look up your code.

- First try to use Resource.Load TextAsset ;

[TextAsset](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextAsset.html)

[Resources.Load](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html)

- Second try use JSONObject or Minijson to load all properties and implement in one class :

[JSONobject](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/710)

[MiniJSON](https://gist.github.com/darktable/1411710)

Comment: I did that and it didn't fix my problems, but that was because it wasn't a JSON error in the first place.